Children's tv show with robot and imagination
I'm trying to remember a tv show I watched growing up. The characters I remember are

Robot - a person dressed as a robot (but more like a space suit) who acts responsibly
imagination - a flying purple blob thing that causes mischief and asks questions

I believe both characters presented as female and had female sounding voices.
The only other things I remember are a shot of robot tending her plants and something about imagination and a rocket.
I thought it was called "take a look" but I can't find anything by googling that. I could be totally wrong about the name.
I would have watched this in the early 90s on public tv in Utah.

It's called Look Up! by TV Ontario. I was digging for the same answer and came across people discussing it on TV Tropes.

This is certainly the best lead so far, can you link to any sources? Maybe that discussion you mention?
